# Mounting a drive and accessing it

Tags: debian, mount, fstab, automounting

I have created a partition on `/dev/sdb`

I want to be able to go to this drive when I type:

```
cd /name
```

What I did, which did not work.

- `mkdir name` in `/mnt`
- mounted the `/dev/sdb` on `/mnt/name`
- updated the `fstab`: `/dev/sdb   /name   ext3   defaults   0   1`
- `mount -a` (when i do this i get this message: 'the /name is not found')

What am I doing wrong here. Running latest Debian distro

Comment: If you have created a **partition** on `sdb` then is does not make any sense to try mounting `sdb` itself. Given your level of understanding: Why don't you use your distro's tools to do that?

Answer (score 9):

Let's take it from the beginning. First of all, you mount **partitions**, not disks. So, `mount /dev/sdb` won't work, `mount /dev/sdb1` will (assuming you want to mount the 1st partition of `sdb`). To be able to access the drive with `cd /name` you need to either mount it at `/name` or make `/name` a symlink to `/mnt/name`. To actually mount it at `/name` do the following:

```
sudo mkdir /name
sudo chmod 755 /name
```

Add this line to `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/sdb1 /name ext3 defaults 0 1
```

Then mount it: `mount /name`

To mount the partition in `/mnt` and link it to `/name` do

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/name
sudo chmod 755 /mnt/name
sudo ln -s /mnt/name /
```

Add this line to `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/sdb1 /mnt/name ext3 defaults 0 1
```

Then mount it: `mount /mnt/name`

Answer (score 0):

> - mkdir name in /mnt
> - mounted the /dev/sdb on /mnt/name

Those are what you did wrong. That will make it available at `/mnt/name`. Try using `/name` in both cases.

Comment: Well, if I create a '/name' in the root directory and try to mount '/dev/sdb' to '/home', I get a message saying that _mount point '/name' does not exist_